# Help me ID this bike

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I purchased an old bike and I can't quite find out which brand and model it is. I know it has an Aluminium Kinesis frame , which is pretty light . The bike weights about 9,5kg with the bottle holders and the bike saddle bag on.

It has the Shimano FC-1056 crankset, Shimano BR-1055 brakes , Shimano 5500 front derailleur,hubs and Shimano Ultegra RD-6500(I broke it , got a new model) with Shimano ST-6500 brifters.

The headset is Apollo , stem UNO Kalloy , handlebar Modolo 6QEven. The frame looks to be in a perfect shape , no bents , no scratches.The rims are Mavic CXP 30. The bottom bracket serial is : K(or H)25200227.

[image: cannondale road bike]

[image: Kinesis frame sticker]

Here's the album : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOPMe.jpg

P.S After all the help I got from BikeWrench (which I appreciate), I decided to try my luck and search for the bike model. After 2 days of seaching, I didn't find anything. P.S.S Sorry for my english. Not my native language.

Comment: It would help if you listed the country you're in (I'm going to guess Romania).

Comment: Currently in Germany. Bought it from Germany . The price was 250 euros. After more searches it comes up as an Cannondale R400 but the problem is that the serial number and frame don't match with cannondale but with Raleigh. Strange. Also the derailleur hanger is this one : http://www.ebay.de/itm/Patte-de-Derailleur-CNC-WHEELS-MFG-42-BIANCHI-KONA-JAMIS-REDLINE-Hanger-Sc-/231470715492?hash=item35e4bad264

Answer (score 1):

Try making contact with either of these.  Their logo is almost identical to the decal on your bike.

- http://www.kinesis.com.tw/?lang=2&TTo=en
- http://www.kinesisbikes.co.uk/

Possibly this one, but less likely:

- http://cannibale-bikes.e-monsite.com/